# Export to PDF Dashboard with Performance Point

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, dashboard-designer-2013

I have a small problem, I want to know if there's someone who has succeeded to a PDF export on dashboards with Performance Point in SharePoint 2013? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Our solution didn't find a way, we just had to re-implement the required charts in SSRS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I totally understand

Is what you can give me a solution to convert my dashboard so that it is accesible from SSRS, like that I put out the subscriptions on the server RS reports for automatic export.

Thank you in advance